# Does System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler depend on the Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, system.reactive

Does `System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler` depend on the Windows Task Scheduler in any way? This may seem like a crazy question to anyone who knows the library well, but it also seems very difficult to Google...

I'm using the `System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Default.SchedulePeriodic` method in some Windows Service code.

The service startup times out if I try to start it automatically when the server boots (`ServiceStartMode.Automatic`), but will start fine a minute or so later.

Before I go deeper into trying to diagnose the problem, I'm trying to rule out the fact that my service has a dependency on another service which I haven't declared in the installer.

I've tried looking at the `System.Reactive` [source on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive), but searching for "Task" or "Scheduler" returns a huge number of results (as I'd expect!) and everything is very abstracted, so I'm just not getting anywhere.

Can anyone enlighten me, please?

Comment: Barring Paul Betts answering this, your best bet would be to probably raise this as an issue over on the GitHub, as you're more likely to get people that are involved in the development.

Comment: @Clint Thanks, it's an idea—I was wary about using the issue tracker just to ask questions, but maybe I can find someone there to message about it.

Comment: Can you provide a simple repro?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I'm not sure what a repro would be, in this case—I'm not asking for help fixing code, I'm just asking whether the library has a particular dependency.

Comment: I have opened an issue here, so we'll see what happens: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no: [there is no dependency on the Task Scheduler service](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/967).